# Failed to load motion_planning_rviz_plugin.so

Tags: ros, motion-planning, rviz, arm-navigation, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

To visualize the path generated by OMPL, I follow this [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Calling%20the%20joint%20space%20planner) tutorial.

Unluckly, when adding a Planning Display on rviz, I got:

```
[ERROR] [1336877297.396395409]: The plugin for class 'motiong_planning_rviz_plugin/Planning' failed to load.  Error: Failed to load library /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/lib/libmotion_planning_rviz_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: No manifest in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/lib/libmotion_planning_rviz_plugin.so: motiong_planning_rviz_plugin__Planning
```

How could I solve above errors?

Do you think a typo (extra 'g') on "... 'motiong_planning_rviz_plugin/Planning'..." contributes to the error?

I also wonder why the Planning Display on rviz subcribes motion_planning_msgs::KinematicPath instead of arm_navigation_msgs::DisplayTrajectory.
What do you think?

I am using ROS Fuerte, Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit and arm_navigation stack installed with

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-arm-navigation
```

Thank you.
\update: A [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5444) has been filed for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33864/failed-to-load-motion_planning_rviz_plugin.so/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The extra 'g' is definitely a problem. I wonder how it ended up in your RViz config. Usually, you should be able to load the plugin by clicking "Plugins" -> "Manage..." and checking both check boxes ("Loaded" and "Auto Load") next to "Motion Planning".

Maybe it helps if you delete your `~/.rviz/` config directory first.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-05-14**:
Hi Martin, that typo is in motion_planning_rviz_plugin/plugin_description.xml; https://kforge.ros.org/armnavigation/armnavigation/file/1e25b730b303/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/plugin_description.xml, I have tried to correct it, but the problem remains, any ideas pls?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-05-14**:
Good catch! You should file a bug [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=motion+planning&type=defect&&motion+planning) and edit your question to include a link to the bug report.

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-05-14**:
Martin, btw, I do not see a Plugins button in rviz, where is it? In my case, the motion_planning_rviz_plugin is already in DisplayType windows without any efforts, so I am not sure whether this is correct.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-05-15**:
Yes, that is how it should be. Thanks for submitting the bug report!

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-05-25**:
Hi Martin, do you have any suggestions as workarounds for that please? Thanks.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-05-28**:
You could copy the package to your home directory, fix it there and put it on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.